# Youtube's 8px wide scrollbars on desktop, I'd like to have them normal width

Tags: youtube, css

My question is about the Youtube website on desktop chrome, and how google have modified the scrollbars width to a nearly unusable level, namely 8 pixels wide.

In [this](https://superuser.com/questions/380629/is-there-a-way-to-disable-custom-webkit-scrollbars/1585452#1585452) question, a reply provided by user @ubershmekel stops the css changes to scrollbars completely. It works wonderfully, it stop the YouTube hacks and they remain looking normal. I'd be happy enough with that, but they do look a bit out of place being normal grey on my dark theme.

I was wondering if anyone knows how to do a less forceful attack on their css than that script does, and simply stop the change that's actually changing the width. I don't mind the colour and style of the new ones, I just don't want them so narrow to be almost unusable.

I've tried doing a rule.selectorText.replace('::webkit-scrollbars { width: 8px; }', '') in my greasemonkey script but it didn't work out. I imagine you can't write back to selectorText. I also tried narrowing the filter on the if statement so that it only matched selectorText if it had that string in it, hoping I'd leave all the other css alone, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Re your first paragraph. The rep limitation is precisely to stop people posting new questions in comments or answers. This would appear to be a 'new question' even though based on the other, so therefore should **be** a new question, with reference back to the old. You ought to word it as a new question, keep the ref to the old, & remove the meta-commentary about **why** it's done that way.

Comment: Edited as per your suggestion